# Cordova SQLite UTF8 throws error on insert

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, utf-8

I have an app written with ionic and cordova that inserts names in a database. The db connection is opened like so:

```
var db = window.openDatabase('zpassplus', '1.0', 'ZPass+', 1000000);
```

Then data is fetched from the server via an http, then inserted into a table like so:

```
         $http({
                    url: settings().api_host + 'contact?token=' + $rootScope.authToken,
                    method: "GET",
                    data: {'token': $rootScope.authToken},
                    headers: {
                                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
                    }
                })
        .success(function(data, status) {
            if(data.success === true) {
                db.transaction(function(tx) {

                    for(var i in data.data.contact.contactRiders)
                    {
                        var sqlString, active, rider = data.data.contact.contactRiders[i];

                        if(rider.active) {
                            active = 1;
                        } else {
                            active = 0;
                        }

                        sqlString = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO riders (fname,lname,imagedata,active,riderId) VALUES('" + rider.firstName + "','" + rider.lastName + "','" + $rootScope.defaultPortrait +"'," + active + "," + rider.riderId + ")";

                        console.log("insert into riders: " + sqlString);
                        tx.executeSql(sqlString);
                    }

                }, function(err) {
                    //error callback
                    console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.message);
                }, function(){
                    // this should be the last thing
                    console.log("rider insert success");
                    $location.path('/activity');
                    $rootScope.$apply();
                });
            }
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            // ummm ....
        });
```

The problem is this, when a utf8 string is passed as one of the `rider` properties, the SQL statement fails. Because I have that console.log just before the execute I have the offending SQL statement, it is:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO riders (fname,lname,imagedata,active,riderId) VALUES('Nñicole','Rock','<base64 endcode image here>',1,8824)
```

The error it throws is this:

```
Error processing SQL: near "t": syntax error
```

I ran this same routine with an empty string for the base64 encoded image string, and got the same error and again ran it with an empty string for the first name, and it succeeded. So I'm quite sure its the ñ that's causing the problem. But I can't duplicate it in the command line or anywhere else. Further, it seems that SQLite should be perfectly comfortable with UTF8. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you inserted the meta tag in your header `<meta charset="UTF-8">`? Also can you check inserting the string without the **ñ** character in `Nñicole` i.e `Nicole`? Also check what is the character encoding value of **ñ** for e.g var tempStr = 'Nñicole'; console.log('Value:', tempStr.charCodeAt(1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long crazy goose chance, I have finally solved this issue. For anyone running into this laster, the issue was escaping single quotes. The lines above:

```
sqlString = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO riders (fname,lname,imagedata,active,riderId) VALUES('" + rider.firstName + "','" + rider.lastName + "','" + $rootScope.defaultPortrait +"'," + active + "," + rider.riderId + ")";

console.log("insert into riders: " + sqlString);
tx.executeSql(sqlString);
```

have been changed to:

```
var params;
var sqlString = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO riders (fname,lname,imagedata,active,riderId) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";

if(rider.portraitIncluded === true) {
    params = [rider.firstName, rider.lastName, rider.portrait, active, rider.riderId];
} else {
    params = [rider.firstName, rider.lastName, $rootScope.defaultPortrait, active, rider.riderId];
}

console.log("insert into riders: " + sqlString);
tx.executeSql(sqlString, params);
```

My debugging replaced all instances of `first_name` so I missed another student with name O'Brian or something.

Tips:

1) Always use prepared statements
2) Don't debug like a synchronous program, the last `console.log` written occurred after the bad SQL was executed but before the error was thrown. 
3) UTF8 works just fine in cordova/javascript/http if you think that's your problem, you're probably wrong.